# How does the photon detector in this video work?

Tags: visible-light, photons, double-slit-experiment

In this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9tKncAdlHQ
How does this photon detector at 6:58 work, mechanically speaking? Is this basically just like a camera, that beeps when it is hit by light?

But how can it trace the path of the photon if the photon does not hit it and instead hits the screen - does it register electric radiation, or EM radiation, emitted by the photon, and thus can track a photon from the "side"?

At 8:03 he notes that the result changes if you unplug the detector. I am assuming that this is explained by some sort of observer effect, but what is that observer effect exactly - what is changing physically when you unplug the detector? Is the detector just like a camera or does it, itself, emit radiation?

I also don't know how literally to take his use of the term "unplug", maybe he means physical removal of the detector...?

Also, is there video anywhere online of the experiment being performed with this specific photon detector type mentioned in the video?

If any of my understanding is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: In the video you linked, isn’t he describing the experiment conducted with atoms?

Comment: My apologies, thank you for pointing that out. Is there a different detector used for atoms…?